# Не выходит изменить цвет текста в Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

Пытался изменить цвет текста в `spinner` (у меня он, по умолчанию, белый и на фоне белого `LinearLayout`). Пробовал изменить цвет текста в .xml файле `simple_spinner_item`, но текст как был белым, так и остался.

Что я сделал не так или как изменить цвет (если этот способ не работает. Я хотел поставить адаптер, но понял, что не знаю, как перехватить текст...).

Вот `simple_spinner_item`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

И код установки адаптера:

```
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input_words_spinner_1);

            ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.times, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же в коде стандартный айтем вставляете, а не ваш кастомный:

> adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

Надо же быть внимательней и делать так:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Comment: И для `DropDown` тоже?О.о

Comment: Я не знаю. Но в приведённом вами коде вы нигде свою разметку не используете. Я не помню как это для спинера делать, но точно не так как вы пытаетесь. Собственно вы даже не пытаетесь в вашем коде свою разметку использовать.

Comment: Упс... Старый код привел (откатывался к нему). Помогло! Но теперь пункты маленькие и черные (но текст чернее)...